# How can I download my all instagaram posts with captions?

Tags: download, instagram, posts

I want to Download my all Instagram posts with captions in high quality. how can I do so? Or is there a way to share a post of my instagram in other instagram account?

Comment: The almighty Google search may answer your questions

Comment: I cannot find any answer there that is why i posted here

Comment: Type in Google search 'mass planner alternative'

Answer (score 0):

You can use a downloader, like this one.

http://imristo.com/instagram-downloader-download-instagram-photo-video/

It allows you to download photos from user and save all media details to CSV (Excel) file.